# Package abandoned how to remove it?

Tags: laravel-5

I tried to remove an abandoned package from my project but got the following warning in my shell:

```
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-color is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-color instead.
Package jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use php-parallel-lint/php-console-highlighter instead.
```

I've already installed the new packages but the warning still continues to show. How can I get rid of this warning?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ignore warnings until it has been removed as a package dependency from the collision package

see: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/jakub-onderka-package-abandoned-warnings

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 9):

These packages are used by `nunomaduro/collision` which is a Laravel dependency.

The package creator Tweeted out the issue was fixed on April 4th 2020*

Therefore, a `composer update` should bring in the new version of `collision` without the dependency and remove the warning.

**Please note:** These packages may also be used by other composer packages you are using so there's no guarantee this will work.

* Tweet: https://twitter.com/enunomaduro/status/1246531267023290370

Answer (score 8):

One can normally find out what is depending on an outdated package with this command:

```sh
composer depends --tree jakub-onderka/php-console-color
```

In this case it might show something like this:

```
jakub-onderka/php-console-color v0.2
└──jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter v0.4 (requires jakub-onderka/php-console-color ~0.2)
   └──psy/psysh v0.9.9 (requires jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter 0.3.*|0.4.*)
      └──laravel/tinker v1.0.8 (requires psy/psysh 0.7.*|0.8.*|0.9.*)
         └──your/project (requires laravel/tinker ^1.0)
```